# Spatial Statistics in mapinfo 15 64 bit

Tags: mapinfo, spatial-statistics

How can I get spatial statistics on my vector (tab) data in MI 15 64-bit. I just need to see total line lengths, areas etc as appropriate.

From the MI help I tried the following

> To see the details of a data record:
>
> Open a .TAB file with statistical data in it. Select a geographical
>   object in the Map window. On the HOME tab, in the Tool Windows group,
>   click Statistics.

But all I get is

> Table CCRC_Road_Centerline_NEW has 464 records selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just realised that it's simply the same process as in older mapinfo versions ...

so Sum(ObjectLen(obj,"m"))"Length_m"

[image]

Thanks to http://web.pb.com/mapinfopro-oct-2013/Query-Ninja-Calculating-Line-Objects-Length/?webSyncID=46d43e17-2562-4890-a3d6-aae32714dc02